# Centering an equation

Tags: equations, alignment

```
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt] {article}
\usepackage{epsf}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
Suppose we have a circle with radius $r=1$ inscribed within a square. Then the area ratio is:
    \begin{gather*}
        \begin{align*}
            \dfrac{\text{Area of circle}}{\text{Area of square}}=\dfrac{\pi r^2}{4r^2}=\dfrac{\pi}{4}
        \end{align*}
    \end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

To align the quation in centre, I tried `gather*`, `align*` separately too but nothing worked for me.

Comment: centre is the default, you are explicitly specifying flush left equations `fleqn`  you can not use `align` in `gather`

Comment: you shouldn't be using `epsf` in any latex document written after 1990 or so

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Solved! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Some comments, in no particular order:

- Since you want to create a one-line unnumbered, centered displayed equation, there's no need or justification for using embedded `align*` and `gather*` environments; instead, just use `\[` and `\]`.
- Since you want to center the unnumbered equation, get rid of the `fleqn` option. The user guide of the `amsmath` package states that the option serves to "position equations at a fixed indent from the left margin rather than centered in the text column".
- Since a standalone equation is in display-math mode by default, there's no need for `\dfrac`; the less-ostentatious `\frac` macro will do just fine.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\text" macro
\begin{document}
Suppose we have a circle with radius $r=1$ inscribed 
within a square. Then the area ratio is:
\[
\frac{\text{Area of circle}}{\text{Area of square}} =
\frac{\pi r^2}{(2r)^2} = 
\frac{\pi}{4}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `fleqn` is actually short for "full length equations".  Flush-left positioning of the leftmost component is a consequence.  (Otherwise, solid analysis.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton -- Good catch! Let me fix this right away...